# PHP script to go through each line of CSV and use IF statement

Tags: php, csv

I am new to PHP and am trying to create a script that goes through a CSV.

For each row (excluding the headers), checks to see if column 2 and 3 (total rows being 0,1,2,3) when combined, are greater or equal to 1; then display a "1" in column 1. If column 2 and 3 are less than 1, then display "0" in column 1.

An example of the CSV is displayed below:-

```
sku,is_in_stock,warehouse_3,warehouse_4
AP-STYLUS,1,20,5
RC-3049,0,0,0
NFNC-FLAT-CAP,1,20,20
NFNC-HOOD14-ZIP-S,1,0,5
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Please show us some code you've tried.

Comment: @LukeAppel thanks for the edit :-) did the code work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace file.csv with the real filename.

```
<?php

$str = file_get_contents("file.csv");
//$str = "sku,is_in_stock,warehouse_3,warehouse_4
AP-STYLUS,0,20,5
RC-3049,0,0,0
NFNC-FLAT-CAP,0,20,20
NFNC-HOOD14-ZIP-S,1,0,5";

$arr = explode("\n", $str);

$result = array();

Foreach($arr as $line){
     $linearr = explode(",", $line);
     if(is_numeric($linearr[2])){
         if($linearr[2]+$linearr[3]>=1){
               $linearr[1]="1";
               $line = implode("," , $linearr);
         }else{
               $linearr[1]="0";
               $line = implode("," , $linearr);
         }
     }
     $result[]=$line;
}


$newstr = implode("\n", $result);

file_put_contents("file.csv", $newstr);

?>
```

Edit, sorry forgot about the "0" part.
https://3v4l.org/63vmh

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed! I did edit your put_file_contents and changed it to file_put_contents but apart from that it worked perfectly.

Comment: @LukeAppel no problem! Just accept the answer please. And again, thanks for the edit :-)